# NodeJS - Bluebird: wait for loop to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

Having some difficulties solving what should be a simple thing.
I am using NodeJS, and mongodb and have also installed Bluebird for using promises.

I have a simple for-loop where I create a bunch of random names, and push them in an array, like this:

```
const PlayerGenerator = () => {
   var playerArray = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      const player = new Player({
         name: 'Player' + Math.random() * 100
      })
      playerArray.push(player)
   }

   return playerArray

}
```

I want to write all these names to my database, but not quiet sure how to set up my promises correctly so every player gets written to my databse.

```
server.get('api/team/new', (req, res, next) => {
    const player = PlayerGenerator()
    // This array contains 15 players with the exact same name.
})
```

From what I have read in different threads here, promises seems to be the best way to solve this, but like I mentioned above, not quiet sure how to set it up and is looking for a bit of advice.

Comment: Why do you think promises will help you here? Promises are extremely generic things used for chaining functionality with asynchronous actions such as XHRequests. Where is the issue? Are you unable to write to your database? 
'const PlayerGenerator' looks entirely synchronous too, there's no point using promises here. Also, why are you using 'const' if you're just going to write this data to a database?
Also, promises are pretty much fully implemented in ES6+node, why bother overcomplicating things with a library like Bluebird?

Comment: To be a bit more succinct  *"There is no async code here"*. So "maybe" your `Player` objects require actual creation in the database and you want to only return after they are actually created. Is that what you are asking here? Because `new Player()` is presumable not an async method. Unless of course you are hiding something we don't know about. By my "guess" is that this is just a mongoose model reference. So not aync. Yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you are going about this the wrong way, as their seems a far more simple and logical approach to what you seem to be otherthinking.

All you really want to do is *"create 15 randomly named players in the database"*, and eschewing better methods to get unique random names ( because the current method isn't "uniquely" random ), all you really need to do is pass an array of plain objects directly to `Player.create()`, since your history on this says you are using mongoose anyway:

```
Player.create(
  Array.apply(null,Array(15)).map(() => {
    return { "name": "Player" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) }
  })
).then((players) => {
  console.log(players)
});
```

Which is just going to give you output something like:

```
[ { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79eb, name: 'Player87', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79ec, name: 'Player29', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79ed, name: 'Player81', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79ee, name: 'Player52', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79ef, name: 'Player12', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f0, name: 'Player93', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f1, name: 'Player69', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f2, name: 'Player88', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f3, name: 'Player81', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f4, name: 'Player48', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f5, name: 'Player38', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f6, name: 'Player82', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f7, name: 'Player47', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f8, name: 'Player85', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56f7488242727e6c308f79f9, name: 'Player26', __v: 0 } ]
```

That seems to make the most sense since it is actually just one call to the database anyway as MongoDB allows you to specify more than one document to insert in a single statement.

Of course, if you just want to play with promise resolution then just use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which again does not really need the inclusion of Bluebird here, especially if you are already running with ES6 constructs.

Simply return the `Promise` from [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) and then resolve later:

```
  var playerPromises = Array.apply(null,Array(15)).map(() => {
    return Player.create({ "name": "Player" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) });
  });

  Promise.all(playerPromises).then((players) => {
      console.log(players);
  });
```

So in that case you are just using the `Promise` returned by `.create()` and resolving each into the resulting array. But it is of course actually writing to the database *"fifteen times"*, when you could have sent just *"one"* request instead.

For my two cents, just supply an array of the things you want to create directly to `.create()`. Whilst there are use cases for resolving an array of promises, this is really not one in which that is the most optimal solution.